# I am looking for a list of mapping libraries?

Tags: api, comparison

I am looking for the top APIs that I can use to display maps from a number of map servers/sources. (like openlayers and openscales). So are there any other popular APIs for **other languages than javascript and flex** (C++,Java,C#... ) ?
(it doesn't matter if it is free or not)

Comment: Are you looking for desktop or web solutions? The question is a little confusing since openlayers is javascript.

Comment: Both Web and Desktop

Comment: This is a really broad question. Do you have any specific use case or are you really just looking for a list of project names?

Comment: A shopping question. I think it should be closed unless it is modified. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Answer (score 2):

Well you can always use QGIS with its Python API to create a standalone application.

http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/

https://github.com/NathanW2/pyqgis-playground/blob/master/canvas/canvas.py

Answer (score 1):

[BruTile](http://brutile.codeplex.com/) is a potential C# option - open source and active. That gets you into the C# / .net world (desktop applications, silverlight, etc). There are libraries that use BruTile that provide higher level abstractions - they are listed on the website.

If that doesn't help you, a much more detailed question might produce a more useful answer.